# Jquery load with script tags

Tags: jquery, load

I read something about the `.load` function in jQuery. Is there a way to insert the script tags in the loaded page?

When I try to load a page the scripts doesn't load :s, I want to fix this. And `getscript()` isn't a option.

Comment: Don't look for a different solution to avoid the problem. You should figure out why the script doesn't load, or use [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

Answer (score 8):

When `.load()` returns HTML content that contains `<script>` tags, jQuery strips out the     `<script>` tags, moves them,<sup>1</sup> executes them, and then removes them.

While this makes it hard to step through those scripts with a debugger, the scripts *do* execute.

#### See also

- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1605-jQuery-AJAX-Strips-Script-Tags-And-Inserts-Them-After-Parent-Most-Elements.htm
- http://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-load-with-script-tags-doesn-t-work

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Either to the `<head>`, or the parentmost element — I haven't found an authoritative source on this yet, though I could just check the jQuery source...</sub>

Comment: Its not exactly true, at least now (version 1.9). [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution) says that script tags will be executed only if there is no suffixed selector expression. It means that `$('selector').load('my-url #other-selector')` will not execute script tags contained in the `#other-selector` node. They call it a feature but for me it's rather a bug ...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using $(el).load I did a $.get, parsed the result en ev(i)lled ;) the scripts

For readibility and understanding I've tried to use variablenames that reflect their purpose and simplified it a lot. Ofcourse there should be some error handling here, but it's just a POC. HTH someone :)

Below *le code

```
var ajax_url = "mypage.htm";
var result_selector_filter = "#mynewcontent";
var element_to_update = $("#mycontent");

// below the statement that you'ld normally use
// element_to_update.load(ajax_url + ' ' + result_selector_filter);

$.get(ajax_url, function(response){
    // parse the entire response into a jQuery object
    var initial_parsed_result = $(response);
    // find the selector that needed to be filtered
    var result_node = initial_parsed_result.find(result_selector_filter);

    // update the html
    element_to_update.html(result_node.html());

    // variables used while looping
    var current_node,i;

    // Loop the parsed result jQuery object, check if it's a script tag and evaluate it
    for(i=0;i<initial_parsed_result.length;i++){
        // create a jquery object for current looped result html
        current_node = $(initial_parsed_result.get(i));
        // check if current node is a script tag
        // method always returns the tagname in CAPITALS
        if(current_node.prop("tagName")=="SCRIPT") {
            eval(current_node.html());
        }
    }
});
```