# .ready to load in html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code. I want to load the content **after everything** else has loaded. But it seems I can only load **html** and not **javascript**:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#twitter_left").html("<p><img align='left' alt='Twitter Bird' src='/sites/all/themes/helixTheme/images/twitter-bird.png' /><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Follow Us On Twitter</strong></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><script charset='utf-8' src='http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js'></script><script>new TWTR.Widget({version: 2,type: 'profile',rpp: 7,interval: 30000,width: 'auto',height: 800,theme: {shell: {background: '#dbe5ff',color: '#333333'},tweets: {background: '#ffffff',color: '#999999',links: '#f26422'}},features: {scrollbar: false,loop: true,live: false,behavior: 'default'}}).render().setUser('helixwebsites').start();</script></p>");});
```

So my next plan was to put the content in a html file and use the `.load` handler, but I still want it to load after all of the page has.

Comment: You can load JavaScript with [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery load with script tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952123/jquery-load-with-script-tags)

Answer (score 1):

You can load all the javascript you want.  In between the:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

you can write any javascript you want.  It can be jQuery or non jQuery javascript code.  Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Document is now ready");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("body").append("<h1>insert html dynamically</h1>");

  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  var code = "alert('insert script dynamically');";
  $(script).append(code);
  $("body").append(script);

  var script2 = document.createElement('script');
  script2.type = 'text/javascript';
  script2.src = 'path/your/javascript.js';
  $("body").append(script2);

});
```

in your code:

```
$("#twitter_left").html("<p><img align='left' alt='Twitter Bird' src='/sites/all/themes/helixTheme/images/twitter-bird.png' /><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Follow Us On Twitter</strong></p><p>&nbsp;</p>");
$("#twitter_left").append(script2);
```

Load javascript in new window:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var newPage = window.open('', '_blank');
  newPage.document.write("<h1>insert html dynamically</h1>");
  newPage.document.write("<script>alert(1)</" + "script>");
});
```

Comment: Using a variation of yours this is what I have:   $(document).ready(function () {
  var script2 = document.createElement('script');
  script2.type = 'text/javascript';
  script2.src = 'http://helixwebsites.co.uk/sites/all/themes/helixTheme/twitter.js';
  $("#twitter_left").html("<p><img align='left' alt='Twitter Bird' src='/sites/all/themes/helixTheme/images/twitter-bird.png' /><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Follow Us On Twitter</strong></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>" + script2 +"</p>");
  });   but where script2 is supposed to be, it outputs: [object HTMLScriptElement]

Comment: you must use $(selector).append(script2).

Comment: The issue I am getting is that instead of loading inside the target div it reloads as a new page?

Comment: You must open new window and write code inside. Note: Instead of "</script>" write: "</" + "script>"

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you shall use [JQuery getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) function in order to load JavaScript in a dinamic way and then run it.