# Jquery load method to load a html with a script tag into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery load with script tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952123/jquery-load-with-script-tags)

Using Jquery I am trying to load the html into a div holder on click of the tab. HTML loads perfectly into the div. Issue is the script tag present inside the html is not working.

I am just trying to load the code in http://jsfiddle.net/meetravi/UbFcu/ into my div using Jquery.

```
$('#content-holder').load("graph.html");
<div id="content-holder"></div>
```

Now on executing this code without a script tag in the graph.html I could see the html is getting load. when I add the script tag it is not loading into the div. My requirement is I dont want to load the script tag in the parent html.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: Thanks Blaze I will have a look at it. Do you want me to call getScript method inside graph.html?

Comment: @MarcusEkwall May be similar question. but there is no answer approved  in the link you have given.

Comment: Then check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036870/jquery-load-strips-script-tags-workaround